# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER

Tags: ssis, oracle10g, connection, database-connection, odac

It has been a real struggle trying to get this to work on my Windows 7 64-bit machine.

I have a package which moves data from Oracle to SQL and, on our Windows 2008 R2 test server it works fine (within BIDS).

What I have tried so far....

- Copied BIDS from Program Files (x86)  to Program Files (to eliminate
  the brackets issue)
- Installed 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle as well as 32-bit ODAC.
- Tried setting DelayedValidation to TRUE
- Installed TOAD and am able to connect to Oracle database.

Within BIDS, I can test the connection successfully and even preview it, however when I try to execute the package fails on the DataSource task (ie Oracle connection).

Very frustrating and I appreciate any help on this.

Complete error below:

> [OLE DB Source [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "LICS" failed
>   with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before
>   this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call
>   failed.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: component "OLE DB Source" (1) failed validation
>   and returned error code 0xC020801C.

thanks,

KS

Comment: Right click on projec> poperties > Debugging>Run64bitsRuntime>False.

Comment: Thx Maverick, but that is already set to False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys are going to laugh.... but I set Run64bitsRuntime to TRUE and it works lol! I guess it is using the 64-bit driver then - now I'm confused. I dont even want to know whats going on here as long as it works!

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this since your driver is 32 bits.

Right click on project > properties > Debugging > Run64bitsRuntime > False.

Comment: I made it false, however, still getting error.Any other way?